# Ошибка The build must be stopped before the solution can be closed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Создал пустой проект Xamarin.Forms в VS 2017, запускаю через <kbd>F5</kbd> или кнопкой:

[image: Run app]

Потыкал кнопки, работает. Захотел выйти – нажал в эмуляторе на крестик:

[image: Close app]

Однако несмотря на то, что эмулятор закрыт и приложение должно остановиться – студия явно не хочет прекращать работу приложения.

Пункты меню build, rebuild заблокированы, попытка закрыть решение неудачна: выдаёт ошибку

> The build must be stopped before the solution can be closed

И что с ней делать? Это баг студии на проектах xamarin? Или это я неправильно понимаю работу с эмулятором устройств? Если второе, то как нормально останавливать и запускать приложение?

Answer (score 0):

Я по-прежнему не понимаю, баг это или неправильная работа с эмулятором устройств – но зато нашёл рецепт на большом so:

Можно нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> или выбрать в меню Build пункт Cancel.

Ссылки по теме:

- [how to stop“build must be stopped before the solution can be closed”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30780258/5752652)
- [How do I cancel a build that is in progress in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8997430/5752652)